# $X$ is compact iff $C_c(X)$ is Banach

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Problem: Let $X$ be a Hausdorff, $\sigma$-compact and locally compact topological space.  $C_c(X)$ is the space of  continuous functions on $X$ whose supports are compact equipped with the supremum norm. Prove $C_c(X)$ is a Banach space if and only if $X$ is compact.

My attempts: I've already proved the closure of $C_c(X)$ is $C_0(X)$, the space of  continuous functions vanishing at infinity. Actually I showed  $C_c(X)$ is dense in $C_0(X)$, using Urysohn's lemma for locally compact spaces. Now, I don't know how to apply $\sigma$-compactness for the rest. Obviously, if  $X$ is compact then  $C_c(X)$=$C(X)$ so I think it's just needed to prove $X$ is compact if  $C_c(X)$ is Banach.

This question and some related questions have been asked here but they were all missing $\sigma$-compactness and there isn't an answer to any of them either.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: if $C_c(X)$ is Banach, then it is closed in $C_0(X)$. Then, assuming $X$ is noncompact, construct (using $\sigma$-compactness) a function $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that vanishes at infinity but without a compact support.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you Sir for your hint.

Comment: @Mindlack I wrote such $f$ in the comment section below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already know that $\overline{C_c(X)} = C_0(X)$ and the latter is well-known to be a Banach space (everything taken in the sup or $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm). If $C_c(X)$ is Banach (hence complete in that norm) it's clear that we must have $C_c(X) = C_0(X)$ in that case (complete implies closed in a complete superspace).

Now show that if $X$ is $\sigma$-compact locally compact Hausdorff that is **not** compact, there is a function $f$ that vanishes at infinity but does not have compact support. That will give the required contradiction to show that $X$ must in fact be compact. I suggest using that $X$ is hemi-compact: $X$ is a union of a strictly increasing family of compact sets $K_n$ obeying $K_n \subseteq \operatorname{int}(K_{n+1})$ for all $n$, which satisfies that any compact subspace $K$ of $X$ is a subset of some $K_n$. Then with some Urysohn functions you can find $f$ as described..

Comment: Thank you Sir. Although I wasn't familiar with the hemi-compact term, I was trying to use the compact sets you mentioned. But I am still struggling to find $f$ you described. Thank you.

Comment: @Rajaei Keep on thinking.

Comment: Let $f_n$ be $\frac {1}{2^n} $ on $K_n$ and $0$ on $X$ \ $int (K_{n+1})$. I think $f=f_1+f_2+f_3+ ...$ works as the required contradiction. Am I mistaken?

Comment: $f_n$ is the continuous function the Urysohn's lemma gives.

Comment: @Rajaei note that you  use that $X$ is normal, which is true, but must be argued maybe?

Comment: I think there is a version of the Urysohn's lemma for locally compact spaces. I used that. Please tell me if there is something I am missing or I am wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rajaei no, it’s it that. Just a reminder.  $X$ is Lindelöf and regular so $T_4$ and Urysohn just applies.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your time and comments.