# Cc(X) is a Banach algebra iff X is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, complete-spaces

I'm using Cc(X) to mean the 'space of continuous complex-valued functions on X which have compact support'. Naturally I'm assuming X is locally compact. I'm using the usual uniform norm and point wise multiplication.

I've got "X is compact implies Cc(X) is a Banach algebra". I don't think the converse, ie "Cc(X) is a Banach algebra implies X is compact" holds, but I'm struggling to understand completely why.

I've seen the counterexample of X being the first uncountable ordinal which is locally compact but Cc(X) is complete, although I'm not sure if this is a strong enough counterexample in my case.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps these help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267355/x-is-compact-iff-c-cx-is-banach
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2553103/c-cx-is-complete-then-x-is-compact?rq=1

Comment: What's unlcear about that example?

Comment: I think I've got my head around it now, but I thought 'Cc(X) is complete' didn't necessarily imply Cc(X) is a Banach algebra. However, I realise now that (I think) that Cc(X) is in general a normed algebra for any space X hence only completeness is the additional requirement for it to be a Banach algebra.